# How to use return value from one class in another?

Tags: python, pytorch

My code looks like this :

```
class RegularConv(nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__.()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    def forward (self, inputs):
        inputs, indices = self.pool1(inputs)
        return inputs, indices

class UpsamplingConv(nn.module):
    def __init__(self, indices):
        super().__init__.()
        self.unpool = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=2, padding=0)

    def forward (self, output):
        output = self.unpool(output, indices, output_size=output_size)
        return output
class Net(nn.module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__.()
        self.layer1 = RegularConv()
        self.layer2 = UpsamplingConv()

    def forward(self, input):
        input, indices = self.layer1(input)
        input = self.layer2(input, indices)
```

The forward method in `RegularConv` class returns inputs and indices and the forward method in `UpsamplingConv` class has to use those indices.

I use both of these classes in another class `Net`. I want to use the return value from one class and use in another class. I want to pass the returned indices from `RegularConv` as an argument in `UpsamplingConv`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to return it as a list like below,

```
def forward (self, inputs):
        inputs, indices = self.pool1(sub_inputs)
        return [inputs, indices]
```

And use the index of the list to call that parameter out.

```
test = UpsamplingConv(RegularConv()[1])
```